# How can I group with multiple RDDs without aggregate the original RDD's partition?

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I have two RDDs have common variables, which have format like:

```
 x = sc.parallelize([("A", 1), ("B", 4),("A",2)])
 y = sc.parallelize([("A", -1),("B", 5)])
```

Then I want to group with them using the common variable. `"A"` and `"B"`.

I have tried to use the command below:

```
 z = [(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(x.cogroup(y).collect()))]
 print(z)
```

What I got is

```
[('A', ([1, 2], [-1])), ('B', ([4], [5]))]
```

However, the thing I want is

```
[('A', ([1], [-1])), ('B', ([4], [5])),('A', ([2], [-1]))]
```

How can I change the code to get the output like above? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a straight join:

```
print(x.join(y).collect())
#[('A', (1, -1)), ('A', (2, -1)), ('B', (4, 5))]
```

Add in a call to `mapValues` if you want the elements of the `tuple`s to be `list`s:

```
print(x.join(y).mapValues(lambda a: tuple([b] for b in a)).collect())
#[('A', ([1], [-1])), ('A', ([2], [-1])), ('B', ([4], [5]))]
```